# Ruby map method with instance_variables

Tags: ruby

Say I have a class SomeClass with instance variables a and b.

```
def SomeClass
  def initialize a, b
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end
end
```

When I type into pry the following lines

```
someclass = SomeClass.new "one", "two"
someclass.instance_variables
```

As expected it prints an array with symbols

```
[:@a, :@b]
```

now, when I use

```
a.instance_variables.map do |var|
  puts var
end
```

I expect it to print

```
:@a
:@b
```

but what I am getting is

```
@a
@b
```

Can someone please explain this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`puts` transparently calls `to_s` on arguments. [`Symbol#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Symbol.html#method-i-to_s) returns symbol’s name (strings w/out preceding colon.) On the other hand, [`Array#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-inspect) calls `inspect` on nested elements, that’s why you see colons while *putting* array’s instance.

Look:

```
▶ :a.to_s
#=> "a"
▶ [:a,:b,:c].to_s
#=> "[:a, :b, :c]"
```

This is exactly what you yield calling `puts`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print the symbols as 
:@a
:@b
use 'p var', as p calls inspect on its argument unlike puts which calls to_s